# Possible to capture the runtime type supplied to a generic class?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a serializer for `SortedMap<string, T>` sort of object, and I want to populate the object with the name of actual name of T when I serialize an instance (to ease the deserialization logic);

I would like to do this in the constructor somehow, but I don't see methods I can call on "T" in the constructor.  Somwthing like this?

```
  class Foo {
    ...
  }

  class SortedMap<T> {
     memberTypeName : string;

     constructor() {
       this.memberTypeName = [some "type of T" function from which I can get the name?]
     }

     get(key: string) : T { ... }
     add(key: string, item: T) {...}
  }

  let foos = new SortedMap<Foo>();
  console.log(`This map contains ${foos.memberTypeName}s`);


  >This map contains Foos
```

I thought maybe T would have some methods that would let me use some kind of reflection on the Type it represents, or instantiate a T, and get its type from an instance, but intellisense in VS Code, doesn't have any suggestions at all, and `let foo = new T();` doesn't work either (and would require T has a paremeterless constructor I guess)

I thought about using an interface which requires that the T implements a `knowsItsOwnName` sort of property, but that means I wouldn't be able use it on classes I don't author myself.  One other thought was maybe I could interrogate type of T in some kind of proxy when get is called, but that seems like an awfully long way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the type system is [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is compiled to JavaScript, there's no `T` at runtime.  If you want to initialize an instance of `SortedMap<T>` with a string representing the name of the type of `T`, you'll have to pass that string (or something that can produce that string) to its constructor.  For example, assuming your target JavaScript runtime is compatible with ES2015 or later, you can pass a constructor for `T` into your constructor for `SortedMap<T>`, and make use of the fact that class constructors and functions have a [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), like this:

```
class SortedMap<T> {
  memberTypeName: string;

  constructor(ctor: (new (...args: any) => T)) {
    this.memberTypeName = ctor.name;
  }

  get(key: string): T { /* impl */ return null! }
  add(key: string, item: T) { /* impl */ }
}
```

This gives you the behavior you wanted, pretty much:

```
let foos = new SortedMap(Foo);
foos.add("blorp", new Foo());
console.log(`This map contains ${foos.memberTypeName}s`);
// This map contains Foos

let dates = new SortedMap(Date);
dates.add("today", new Date());
console.log(`This map contains ${dates.memberTypeName}s`);
// This map contains Dates
```

Note that you don't need to manually specify the `T` parameter in `new SortedMap(Foo)` or `new SortedMap(Date)`, because the compiler can infer it from the instance types of the `Foo` and `Date` constructors.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-OggrJIqpNP9tuDeyAA)

Comment: That's great -- just what I needed.  I don't understand how it works though.  what is `ctor: (new (...args: any) => T))` doing?

Comment: A value of type `new (...args: any) => T` is a constructor (that's the `new` part) which takes any number of parameters of any types (that's the `(...args): any` part) and returns an instance of type `T` (that's the `=> T` part)

Comment: That nifty.  So If I save `ctor` in the SortedMap, when I need to revive the SortedMap from its JSON representation, I can just call `ctor()` to get a new member item I can populate and put in the revived SortedMap?  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward method to achieve what you need with your syntax. [Since interface information is not available in runtime.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure)

[[You probably can write some plugin for your TypeScript compiler which will do it for you. I don't know limitations there]](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API)

But the most pragmatic way will be to do one of 2 things:

**1. You can create a map where your first argument is generic type:**

```
    let foos = new SortedMap(Foo);
```

Then in your constructor, you can access

```
    Foo.name
```

But that will work if you use classes not interfaces. Passing string to the constructor will do a similar job, but will make refactoring harder though it will work with any interface and class.

**2. When your map has at least one object inside. You can also try to get what you need**

```
    firstFooObjectInMap.constructor.name
```

but that might be not that safe if you have just object literals without a constructor property.

Then you can write your own creative reflection function which will print object structure with keys to console. That is an option if you use object literals and interfaces and don't want to add an extra parameter to the constructor